# Approximating Fourier transformed function with Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Given a function $f(x)$, composed with continuous frequencies in certain interval $[-m,m]$,\begin{equation} f(x) = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-m}^{+m} \hat{f}\Big(\frac{\xi}{a}\Big)e^{\frac{i2\pi x\xi} {a}}d\xi; m\in \mathbb{N} \end{equation} and, if it is to be approximated with only integer frequencies, i.e Fourier series, what is the error $\varDelta_{|n|\leq|m|}  = \tilde{f}(n/a)-\hat{f}(n/a)$ at integer frequencies, given \begin{equation} \tilde{f}(n/a)= \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} f(x) e^{\frac{-i2\pi n x}{a}} dx\end{equation}

is this anyhow connected to fractional Fourier transforms?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Define $\hat{f}$ and $\overline{f}$ in term of $f$. If $\hat{f} = \mathcal{F}[f]$ is continuous and everything converges absolutely then $\sum_n \hat{f}(n) e^{2i \pi nx} = \sum_m f(x+m)$

Comment: Thanks very much, I corrected for mistakes and i made it a better one.

Comment: In time domain $f \to f 1_{|x|< a/2}$ becomes $\hat{f} \mapsto \hat{f} \ast \frac{\sin (\pi a\xi)}{\pi \xi}$ in frequency domain ($\ast$ for convolution). If $\hat{f}$ is compactly supported and $C^1$ you can estimate $\hat{f}-\hat{f} \ast \frac{\sin (\pi a\xi)}{\pi \xi}$ by integrating by parts the latter. In general we replace $f$ by $f   e^{-\pi x^2/n^2}$ to make its Fourier transform $C^\infty$.